# Why is this simple THREE.js javascript particle system not working?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Are there any errors is this code? I am using a new version of Chrome to test on. I've written a similar program that displays a wireframe cube, with no issues. It ran well. I'm thinking I may have written or structured my code incorrectly.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000); 
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 

// create the particle variables
var particleCount = 1000;
var particles = new THREE.Geometry();
var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
  color: 'red',
  size: 20
});

// create the individual particles
for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
  var pX = Math.random()*500 - 250;
  var pY = Math.random()*500 - 250;
  var pZ = Math.random()*500 - 250;
  var particle = new THREE.Vertex(
    new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ)
  );
  particles.vertices.push(particle);
}

// create the particle system
var particleSystem = new THREE.ParticleSystem(
  particles,
  pMaterial);

// add the particle system to the scene
scene.add(particleSystem);

function render() {
  particleSystem.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

I'm not seeing any results, so to speak - just a black canvas element on the page.

Comment: It would help if you would say what results you see and how that differs from what you expect.
To know if there are any (syntax) erors in your code check the browser console.

Comment: I'm not seeing any results, so to speak - just a black canvas element on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks outdated -- as if you copied something from the net, or from an outdated book.

Update to the current version of three.js, and learn from the current three.js examples.

Create your particles like so:

```
var particle = new THREE.Vector3( pX, pY, pZ );
```

Also, `ParticleSystem` is now `PointCloud`, and `ParticleBasicMaterial` is now `PointCloudMaterial`.

three.js r.69